# Mirroring the ROS wiki

Tags: ros, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to mirror the ROS API and wiki docs for a project with no internet access, by following the instructions on the wiki at http://wiki.ros.org/Mirrors#Creating_a_mirror.

The API docs seem to download fine, but mirroring the wiki:

```
rsync -azv wiki.ros.org::wiki_mirror wiki.ros.org --bwlimit=200 --delete
```

fails with

```
@ERROR: Unknown module 'wiki_mirror'
```

Am I missing something here or do the instructions need to be modified?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/109351/mirroring-the-ros-wiki/) by [VC](https://answers.ros.org/users/999/vc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2013-12-11

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-12-11**:
I'm seeing the same problem. I suspect the rsync server isn't set up right, or the documentation is wrong.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-12-12**:
Just tried it, and it works for me (i.e., it starts downloading without error; I cancelled after a few seconds). Maybe they fixed the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yup, the wiki_mirror module is showing up now. Thanks to the team behind ROS once again!!

---

Originally posted by [VC](https://answers.ros.org/users/999/vc/) with karma: 56 on 2013-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-09-15**:
This is failing for me right now.